# how to check open ports in my firewall

Tags: windows, firewall

I have an internet connection from school, where there are restriction about what ports webapp can use. Is it possible, to use my computer to check what ports are allowed to use and can be used? I'm having problem with websockets in couple of locations, so I would like to use client computer to do that. Is there any snippet of code that I can run in chrome console or any command line command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always liked [ShieldsUP!](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2) for checking open ports.

Comment: Okay. this is soo cool, but I use port 10085 for my app, and do not see it in the check.

Comment: Try the "Use specified custom port probe" option.

Answer (score 0):

[nmap](http://nmap.org/book/inst-windows.html#inst-win-exe)

> Nmap ("Network Mapper") is a free and open source (license) utility
>   for network exploration or security auditing. Many systems and network
>   administrators also find it useful for tasks such as network
>   inventory, managing service upgrade schedules, and monitoring host or
>   service uptime

From nmap: [This paper details many of the techniques used to determine what ports (or similar protocol abstraction) of a host are listening for connections](http://nmap.org/nmap_doc.html)